# How to remove the circle?

Tags: edit-mode

On the screen that I use, there was a cross in the middle of the circle. I think, I have entered this mode with "c" and I have found no solution to exit this mode.

[image]

Comment: You're in circle select mode, got to the top left bar where you see a arrow with a circle around it. Just hold down on it and select just the arrow.

Comment: you can press escape

Comment: or right click if you are using left click

Comment: I tried pressing escape and it didn't work. It seems, 2.8 is still quite buggy, I had many "unsmooth" situations.

Comment: I find out that the solution is pressing <kbd>w</kbd> key.

Answer (score 3):

On the toolbar on the left, you can select a tool, such as the Move tool. right now you have the circle select tool enabled (the one highlighted in blue)

Answer (score 1):

You have entered 'circle select' which is the same thing as clicking and dragging  ( box select ) but with a CIRCLE. Right clicking gets you out of this mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy shortcut to this.

Just press `W` on your keyboard to switch between tools, and you will eventually get to *`Box Select`*.